# How to remove duplicate pairs from an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I've an `ArrayList` which contains pairs of integers( say int i, int j). But it may be contains duplicates pairs (like `(int i, int j)` and `(int j, int i)`). Now how can I remove duplicates from it in O(n) time complexity.

#### Updated code:

```
class Pair<t1,t2>
{
    int i, j;
    Pair(int i,int j){
        this.i=i;
        this.j=j;
    }

}

public class My 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair p;
        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> src = Arrays.asList(new Pair(1,2), 
            new Pair(2,3), new Pair(2,1),new Pair(1,2));
        HashSet<String> dest  = new HashSet();

        for(int i=0; i < src.size(); i++) {
            p=src.get(i);
            if(dest.contains(p.j+" "+p.i)) {
                System.out.println("duplicacy");
            }  
            else {
                dest.add(p.i+" "+p.j);
            }
         
        }
        System.out.println("set is = "+dest);
     
        List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> ans=new ArrayList();
        String temp;
        int i,j;
        Iterator<String> it=dest.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) 
        {
            temp=it.next();
            i=Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf(' ')));
            j=Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(temp.indexOf(' 
               ')+1,temp.length()));
            ans.add(new Pair(i,j));
         }
    
         for(Pair i_p:ans) {
             System.out.println("Pair = "+i_p.i+" , "+i_p.j);
         }

     }//end of main method
 }//end of class My
```

This code is working fine but I want to know it performance wise, I mean its overall time complexity ?

Comment: Are you talking about `javafx.util.Pair`? Can you show your code and what you have tried yet? Is `(1, 2)` a duplicate to `(2, 1)`? You should also show your input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **If you can modify `Pair` class, just implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`**:

  ```
  public class Pair {
      private int a;
      private int b;

      public Pair(int a, int b) {
          this.a = a;
          this.b = b;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object o) { 
          if (this == o) return true;
          if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
          Pair pair = (Pair) o;
          return (a == pair.a && b == pair.b) || (a == pair.b && b == pair.a);
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
          return Objects.hashCode(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a,b))); 
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return "Pair{" +
                  "a=" + a +
                  ", b=" + b +
                  '}';
      }
  }
  ```

  Then just create a new `Set<Pair>`:

  ```
  List<Pair> pairs = Arrays.asList(new Pair(1, 2), new Pair(2, 1), new Pair(3, 2));

  Set<Pair> pairSet = new HashSet<>(pairs);

  System.out.println(pairSet);
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [Pair{a=1, b=2}, Pair{a=3, b=2}]
  ```
- **If you can't modify `Pair` class**:

  ```
  List<Pair> pairs = Arrays.asList(new Pair(1, 2), new Pair(2, 1), new Pair(3, 2));

  Set<Pair> pairSet = pairs.stream()
        .map(pair -> new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(pair.getA(), pair.getB())))
        .distinct()
        .map(integers -> {
            Iterator<Integer> iterator = integers.stream().iterator();
            return new Pair(iterator.next(), iterator.next());
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

  System.out.println(pairSet);
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [Pair{a=1, b=2}, Pair{a=2, b=3}]
  ```

---

If you want, you can convert your Set back to a list:

```
List<Pair> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

But it's most likely unnecessary.

Comment: Modifying the Pair class is interesting. But are you sure your second method take O(N)? It contains to **map** and one **collect** method!!!

Comment: every map take O(n) and a collect maximum get O(n) too. The overall is **3n** which is more than *n*. However both has linear complexity O(n).

Comment: @MostNeededRabbit, could you please explain the content of the hashCode() method you created ?

Comment: @Cristiano I wanted to generate a hashcode that will disregard whether the first value was assigned to the first field or to the second field. A set doesn't have order so I used it here.

Answer (score 2):

Make only one loop throught list of Pairs and collect by the way in HashSet processed pair and it's reversed copy:

```
List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> lp = Arrays.asList(new Pair(1,2),
                                               new Pair(2,3),
                                               new Pair(1,2),
                                               new Pair(2,1));
Set<Pair<Integer,Integer>> sp = new HashSet<>();

List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> ulp = lp.stream()
                                    .collect(ArrayList::new,
                                             (l,p)-> { Pair<Integer,Integer> p1 = new Pair(p.getValue(), p.getKey());
                                                       if (!(sp.contains(p))&&!(sp.contains(p1))){
                                                           l.add(p);
                                                           sp.add(p);
                                                           sp.add(p1);
                                                        }} , List::addAll);

System.out.println(ulp);
```

Comment: This not working. It treats (1,2) , (1,2) and (2,1) different.

Answer (score 1):

Since the **contains() of HashSet runs in O(1) time** (See [this](https://gist.github.com/psayre23/c30a821239f4818b0709) and other references) you can use the following method which is the overall O(n):

```
import java.util.*;
import javafx.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           List<Pair<Integer,Integer>> src = Arrays.asList(new Pair(1,2), new Pair(2,3), new Pair(2,1));
           HashSet<Pair<Integer,Integer>> dest  = new HashSet();

            for(int i=0; i < src.size(); i++) {
                if(dest.contains(src.get(i)) || 
                    dest.contains(new Pair(src.get(i).getValue(),src.get(i).getKey()))) {
                    
                }else {
                    dest.add(src.get(i));
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println(dest);

    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**:

You can use `Map.Entry` instead of `javafx.util.pair`. Do the program without Javafx is as follow.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           List<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> src = Arrays.asList(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(1,2), 
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(2,3), new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(2,1));
           HashSet<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> dest  = new HashSet();

            for(int i=0; i < src.size(); i++) {
                if(dest.contains(src.get(i)) || 
                    dest.contains(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(src.get(i).getValue(),src.get(i).getKey()))) {
                    
                }else {
                    dest.add(src.get(i));
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println(dest);

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It treats them different. I think because they are objects like (1,2) is different object from another (1,2). So can you please help me in this ?

Comment: I test it and it worked. Yes objects are different and in this code I check all members. Just copy and paste and run to see the result.

Comment: can you please provide me the actual definition of class Pair with getValue() and getkey() method which you use in your solution.

Comment: Copy and paste my code in [Java online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler) and you can see it works well with O(n) not O(3n). `Pair` is from `javafx.util` . see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html)

Comment: can you do it without using javafx package because I cannot use that package in competitive programming.

Comment: It depends to you! What is actual type of `(i,j)` in your program. It can be Pair or String or even your defined Pair class like accepted answer. What you want for this type?

Comment: (i,j) is a type of integer.

Comment: I'd updated my code please take a look and tell me its overall complexity and performance.

Comment: You have a big mistake to change your question. It might be closed because answers are different from question. Please back your question to previous and ask a new question. Please let me know about new question link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67802484/complexity-of-removing-the-duplicate-element-from-a-list-which-contain-a-pair-of